# ganalytics/wordpress - Demographics and Interest Reports

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have been trying to get the Demographics and Interest Reports working on my many websites and for whatever reason I can't get the reports to validate with any of my wordpress sites. I can get them to work with my home grown ones but none of my WP.

According to GA I have to add the new code and of course turn the switch on to record that specific data (which I did) and works with my handmade sites.

I do not use any plugins for GA with Wordpress because its useless. I just place the code in the footer.php file in between

```
</body><--GACode--></html>
```

and works fine. I have tried to place the code all over my site including the footer, header and nothing seems to allow Google to validate the code. Anyone have any luck with this?

Comment: Have you tried skipping the validation?

Comment: wow.....I feel like an idiot :) solved

Comment: @Blexy please make that a solution so I can mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried skipping the validation?